# Как сделать чтобы кнопка появлялась после отправки сообщения пользователем?

Tags: telebot

Помогите пожалуйста понять как сделать, чтобы после того как клиент введет сообщение в поле ввода и отправит его, появлялась кнопка "Получить просчёт стоимости". Вот что у меня в коде:

```
    if (message.text == '\U0001F4B6 Просчитать авто?'):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        btnback = types.KeyboardButton('\U00002B05 Назад')
        markup.add(btnback)
        msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Чтобы сделать для Вас индивидуальный расчет стоимости, напишите \U0000270F пожалуйста какое авто Вас интересует.\U00002753 \n Например:\n - <b>Марка авто, модель и год</b>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, forward_adm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления кнопки вы можете попробовать сделать следующее:

1. Создать новую кнопку.
2. Изменить markup таким образом, чтобы включить новую кнопку.
3. Определить новый обработчик для кнопки "Получить просчёт стоимости".
4. Внести изменения в функцию `forward_adm()`.

Код:

```
btncalc = types.KeyboardButton('\U0001F4B0 Получить просчёт стоимости')

if (message.text == '\U0001F4B6 Просчитать авто?'):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btnback = types.KeyboardButton('\U00002B05 Назад')
    markup.add(btnback)
    msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Чтобы сделать для Вас индивидуальный расчет стоимости, напишите \U0000270F пожалуйста какое авто Вас интересует.\U00002753 \n Например:\n - <b>Марка авто, модель и год</b>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_price)

def get_price(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Стоимость авто: $10000')


def forward_adm(message):
    bot.send_message(admin_id, message.text)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btnback = types.KeyboardButton('\U00002B05 Назад')
    btncalc = types.KeyboardButton('\U0001F4B0 Получить просчёт стоимости')
    markup.add(btnback, btncalc)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Спасибо, мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.\n\nДля начала нового расчёта, нажмите \U0001F4B6 Просчитать авто?', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз то что нужно. Буду пилить дальше